# method in finding absolute convergence of a given series

Tags: calculus, sequences-and-series, convergence-divergence, divergent-series, absolute-convergence

How do I show absolute convergence for the series

$$\sum_{n=0}^{\infty} \frac{n}{\sqrt{2n^5 +1}}$$

I have already showed by Comparison test that it is convergent. I am after the way of showing $\sum |a_n|$ is convergent. I tried ratio and root test but it gives me a limit of 1 so I need to do another test. I am so stuck in this part. Please help.

Comment: But in this problem $|a_n| = a_n$ so you have already shown it to be true.

Comment: Ahhh. I see. Thank you!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The terms of the series are positive, so if it converges, it converges absolutely. The comparison, ratio and root test are all for absolute convergence.